# Assign a list to variables

Tags: python, google-visualization

I have  a python list:

```
x = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
```

The len() (or list length, which is 3 in this case) of this list can be any number, as it is basically coming from database. My question is: how can I assign each string member of this list into a separate variable automatically? The point over here is: I do not know the number of elements in the list, since they are always different.

Once this is resolved, I am trying to put it into a Python Google Charting (GChartWrapper's pie3d chart) function like this:

```
G.label(aa,bb,cc)
```

However, if I simply put the list in like:

```
G.label(x)
```

then it is naming only one section of the pie chart as the complete list.

Comment: Thinking "Hey, it'd be nice if all these array items were named variables..." is almost always a bad idea. **That's what arrays (or lists) are for.**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[You're doing it wrong.](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

```
G.label(*x)
```